# Prisoner's dilemma strange results

Tags: python, game-theory

I tried to implement a prisoner's dilemma in Python, but my results, instead of showing that tit for tat is a better solution, it is showing that defecting is giving better results.

Can someone look at my code, and tell me what I have done wrong here?

```
import random
from colorama import Fore, Style
import numpy as np
# Define the actions
COOPERATE = 'cooperate'
DEFECT = 'defect'

# Define the strategies
def always_cooperate(history):
    return COOPERATE

def always_defect(history):
    return DEFECT

def random_choice_cooperate(history):
    return COOPERATE if random.random() < 0.75 else DEFECT

def random_choice_defect(history):
    return COOPERATE if random.random() < 0.25 else DEFECT

def random_choice_neutral(history):
    return COOPERATE if random.random() < 0.5 else DEFECT

def tit_for_tat(history):
    if not history:  # If it's the first round, cooperate
        return COOPERATE
    opponent_last_move = history[-1][1]  # Get the opponent's last move
    return opponent_last_move  # Mimic the opponent's last move

def tat_for_tit(history):
    if not history:  # If it's the first round, cooperate
        return DEFECT
    opponent_last_move = history[-1][1]  # Get the opponent's last move
    return opponent_last_move  # Mimic the opponent's last move

def tit_for_two_tats(history):
    if len(history) < 2:  # If it's the first or second round, cooperate
        return COOPERATE
    opponent_last_two_moves = history[-2:]  # Get the opponent's last two moves
    if all(move[1] == DEFECT for move in opponent_last_two_moves):  # If the opponent defected in the last two rounds
        return DEFECT
    return COOPERATE

# Define the payoff matrix
payoff_matrix = {
    (COOPERATE, COOPERATE): (3, 3),
    (COOPERATE, DEFECT): (0, 5),
    (DEFECT, COOPERATE): (5, 0),
    (DEFECT, DEFECT): (1, 1)
}


# Define the players
players = [always_cooperate, always_defect, random_choice_defect, tit_for_tat, tit_for_two_tats, random_choice_cooperate, tat_for_tit, random_choice_neutral]

# Assign a unique color to each player
player_colors = {
    'always_cooperate': Fore.GREEN,
    'always_defect': Fore.RED,
    'tit_for_tat': Fore.BLUE,
    'random_choice_cooperate': Fore.MAGENTA,
    'random_choice_defect': Fore.LIGHTRED_EX,
    'tat_for_tit': Fore.LIGHTYELLOW_EX,
    'random_choice_neutral': Fore.WHITE,
    'tit_for_two_tats': Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX,
}


def tournament(players, rounds=100):
    total_scores = {player.__name__: 0 for player in players}
    for i in range(len(players)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(players)):
            player1 = players[i]
            player2 = players[j]
            history1 = []
            history2 = []
            match_scores = {player1.__name__: 0, player2.__name__: 0}
            # print(f"\n{player1.__name__} vs {player2.__name__}")
            for round in range(rounds):
                move1 = player1(history1)
                move2 = player2(history2)
                score1, score2 = payoff_matrix[(move1, move2)]
                match_scores[player1.__name__] += score1
                match_scores[player2.__name__] += score2
                total_scores[player1.__name__] += score1
                total_scores[player2.__name__] += score2
                history1.append((move1, move2))
                history2.append((move2, move1))
            # print(f"{player1.__name__} moves: {''.join([Fore.GREEN+'O'+Style.RESET_ALL if move[0]==COOPERATE else Fore.RED+'X'+Style.RESET_ALL for move in history1])}")
            # print(f"{player2.__name__} moves: {''.join([Fore.GREEN+'O'+Style.RESET_ALL if move[0]==COOPERATE else Fore.RED+'X'+Style.RESET_ALL for move in history2])}")
            # print(f"Match scores: {player1.__name__} {match_scores[player1.__name__]}, {player2.__name__} {match_scores[player2.__name__]}")  
    sorted_scores = sorted(total_scores.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True)
    return sorted_scores

# Run the tournament
# for player, score in tournament(players):
#     print(f'\nFinal score: {player}: {score}')

num_tournaments = 1000
results = {player.__name__: [] for player in players}

for _ in range(num_tournaments):
    for player, score in tournament(players):
        results[player].append(score)

# Calculate the median score for each player and store them in a list of tuples
medians = [(player, np.median(scores)) for player, scores in results.items()]

# Sort the list of tuples based on the median score
sorted_medians = sorted(medians, key=lambda x: x[1])

num_players = len(sorted_medians)

# Print the sorted median scores with gradient color
for i, (player, median_score) in enumerate(sorted_medians):
    # Calculate the ratio of green and red based on the player's position
    green_ratio = i / (num_players - 1)
    red_ratio = 1 - green_ratio

    # Calculate the green and red components of the color
    green = int(green_ratio * 255)
    red = int(red_ratio * 255)

    # Create the color code
    color_code = f'\033[38;2;{red};{green};0m'
    player_color = player_colors.get(player, Fore.RESET)
    # Print the player name and median score with the color
    print(f'{player_color}{player}: {median_score} coins')
```

The code itself create the matching for 100 rounds. But it then iterate 1000 times to get the median score over many iterations.

Here is the ouput of the results

```
always_cooperate: 1347.024 coins
random_choice_cooperate: 1535.651 coins
tit_for_two_tats: 1561.442 coins
tit_for_tat: 1609.444 coins
tat_for_tit: 1619.43 coins
random_choice_neutral: 1663.855 coins
always_defect: 1711.764 coins
random_choice_defect: 1726.992 coins
```

In [the latest Veritasium video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mScpHTIi-kM) the dilemma is presented with the reward matrix, but *Tit for Tat* is presented as the most efficient solution. I cannot replicate that result, and thus I'm opening this question.

Comment: When you say that "defecting is giving better results," do you mean against tit-for-tat, or averaged against all opponents?

Comment: in general it gets better results against everyone else, on average.
always_cooperate: 1347.024 coins ; random_choice_defect: 1726.992 coins and tit_for_tat: 1609.444 coins

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that is incorrect?

Comment: Well the experiment of Robert Axelrod as presented in the results of Veritasium https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mScpHTIi-kM say that Tit for Tat is the optimal solution

Comment: Was optimal against a particular set of opponents (this set?), or is optimal against any set of opponents?  It cannot be the latter, since clearly "always defect" beats "tit for tat" (they're identical except in the first round).

Comment: btw the only defect I see here, which has no bearing on the results, is that in `def tournament()` your first loop should be: `for i in range(len(players)-1):`.

Comment: @Joe The experiment by Axelrod implement more than my limited set of strategies, but it has at least an always defect, an always cooperate, a random and a tit for tat. They say that among all players, including those I mentionned, Tit for Tat was doing better. More strategies by Axelrod can be found on https://axelrod.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/axelrod/strategies/titfortat.html

Comment: So why do you believe tit-for-tat should be optimal for your set of strategies?

Comment: Once the results are as expected, I recommend checking out [codereview.se].

Comment: Your text says 200 rounds, but doesn't your code only do 100?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the setup of your tournament. It is set up in such a way that `always_defect` never has to play against `always_defect`. So a player of any type never plays against a player of the same type.

It seems to be an advantage to be the only `always_defect` in the group.

Modifying the lines

```
for i in range(len(players)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(players)):
```

to

```
for i in range(len(players)):
    for j in range(i, len(players)):
```

makes it so that an `always_defect` also has to play against an `always_defect`, which changes the picture.

However, I am not 100% sure that the accounting is done correctly for the case that a player type plays against a player of the same type.

Comment: Indeed! Once you have the players plays against "themselves" than result radically change and always_cooperate: 2265.573 coins but tit_for_tat: 2959.367 coins; always_defect: 2719.112 coins

Comment: Could you show sample results with this?

Comment: `
always_cooperate: 3294.0 coins, 
tat_for_tit: 3438.0 coins, 
random_choice_cooperate: 3608.0 coins, 
always_defect: 3624.0 coins, 
tit_for_two_tats: 3721.0 coins, 
random_choice_neutral: 3775.5 coins, 
random_choice_defect: 3789.0 coins, 
tit_for_tat: 3818.0 coins
`

But I used
`
for i in range(len(players)):
        for j in range(len(players)): 
`
to setup the tournament.

(how to add code in comments?)

Comment: Thanks, but would better be in the answer. Although first figure out why you have much different values than @assayag.org reported in the above comment...

Comment: Is the different setup. Its for j in range(I, len(players)): vs for j in range(len(players)):. I am not sure, wich one is correct. The second one has more games, thus more coins.

Comment: I think the one in your answer is correct. Although I tried that myself now and I have tit_for_tat winning with ~2210 coins, much less than assayag.org's 2959.367. @assayag.org, did you do something else?

Comment: I also get  something like ~2210 coins. Maybe @assayag.org modified the number of rounds?

Comment: @Jochen I added new strategies so i think this is why i have more coins. I used 100 rounds just so the match appear on one line.

Comment: @assayag.org - ok, I see. Still puzzling about the accounting. Accounting adds up points for player one and two. In the plays where a player plays against himself, the corresponding strategy scores two times. It seems that the plays against themself are weighted double. That's why I think the 2nd player loop should be for j in range(len(players)).

Comment: (You can't add code in comments. There is the limited `monospace formatting` but no support for newlines, indentation, etc.)

Comment: @Jochen Just to make sure the rounds were correct i added a counter for win, loss, and draws. In my version i have twelve strategies. though: i get always_defect: 10 wins, 0 losses, 3 draws, and always_cooperate: 0 wins, 6 losses, 7 draws.  My current version is there if you wanna compare https://github.com/danass/tatfortit/blob/main/titfortat.py